# ios paypal simple payment with multiple objects

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

**UPDATED CODE**
thanks to ragnesh I am able to do multiple items payment but without a discount, i needed a 10% discount on each product, can anyone help regarding this?

```
- (void)simplePayment {
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].shippingEnabled = TRUE;

    [PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = TRUE;

    [PayPal getPayPalInst].feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];

    payment.recipient = @"email@example.com";
    payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";

    payment.invoiceData = [[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init];

    payment.invoiceData.totalShipping = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];

    payment.invoiceData.totalTax = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.00"];

    payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSMutableDictionary * dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [db.array count]; i++) {
            myData =[db.array objectAtIndex:i];
        [dic setValue:myData.itemName forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"title%d",i]];
        [dic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myData.itemPrice] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"price%d",i]];
        [dic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myData.itemQuantity] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"quantity%d",i]];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",dic);


    for (int i=0; i<[db.array count]; i++) {
        PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init];
        [item setItemCount:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"quantity%d",i]]]];
        [item setItemPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"price%d",i]]]];
        item.name = [dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"title%d",i]];

        [payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];


        NSDecimalNumber *paypalItemQuantity = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"quantity%d",i]]];

        NSDecimalNumber *paypalItemPrice = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"price%d",i]]];


        payment.subTotal =[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[payment.subTotal floatValue]
                                                                 +[paypalItemPrice floatValue] *

                                                                 [paypalItemQuantity floatValue]

                                                                 ]];


        NSLog(@"%@",[dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"price%d",i]]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"title%d",i]]);
        NSLog(@"%@",payment.subTotal);


    }

    [[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
}
```

**for discount i did something like that: but it pops up error**

```
payment.subTotal =[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",([payment.subTotal floatValue]*

                                                                 [paypalItemQuantity floatValue])
                                                                 -([paypalItemPrice floatValue] *

                                                                 [paypalItemQuantity floatValue] *0.1)

                                                                 ]];
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: the error coming is that the amounts specified for item,price,tax and shipping don't add up to total amount

Comment: i have put my updated latest code, try to put the line out of the loop too. but still problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this for [payPal](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2012/12/paypal-sdk-for-ios.html?q=paypal) integration

Put this line out of your loop

```
payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];
```

**EDIT**

```
- (void)simplePayment
{
    //dismiss any native keyboards

    //optional, set shippingEnabled to TRUE if you want to display shipping
    //options to the user, default: TRUE
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].shippingEnabled = TRUE;

    //optional, set dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled to TRUE if you want to compute
    //shipping and tax based on the user's address choice, default: FALSE
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].dynamicAmountUpdateEnabled = TRUE;

    //optional, choose who pays the fee, default: FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER
    [PayPal getPayPalInst].feePayer = FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER;


    //for a payment with a single recipient, use a PayPalPayment object
    NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"drinkDetailDic"];


    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];

    payment.recipient = @"email@example.com";
    payment.paymentCurrency = @"USD";

    payment.description = [dic objectForKey:@"title"];


    //invoiceData is a PayPalInvoiceData object which contains tax, shipping, and a list of PayPalInvoiceItem objects
    payment.invoiceData = [[PayPalInvoiceData alloc] init];

    //shippping charge
    payment.invoiceData.totalShipping = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0"];

    payment.invoiceData.totalTax = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.00"];

    payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems = [NSMutableArray array];


    for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        PayPalInvoiceItem *item = [[PayPalInvoiceItem alloc] init];
        item.totalPrice = payment.subTotal;
        [item setItemCount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        [item setItemPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"price"]]];
        item.name = [dic objectForKey:@"title"];

        [payment.invoiceData.invoiceItems addObject:item];

        payment.subTotal =[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[payment.subTotal floatValue]
                                                                     +[[dic objectForKey:@"price"] floatValue]]];

    }

    [[PayPal getPayPalInst] checkoutWithPayment:payment];
}
```

**NOTE**

If you are adding multiple item then subTotal price is same as sum of all item price.

Comment: you can check my answer its working.... you have to add all item in array and subTotal may be same as allItemPrice count

Comment: i have updated my code, from your help its working without discount, i needed to give it 10% discount too, i try many things but not working can u help in this too. thanks

Comment: Bro now make your logic and iteration :)

Comment: i tried so many different things but then the error coming is that the amounts specified for item,price,tax and shipping don't add up to total amount

Comment: apply your 10% discount on particular item too [item setItemPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[dic objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"price%d",i]]]];