# Adding paypal payment in android and iphone app

Tags: android, iphone, html

I am developing a mobile app for android and iphone. For common approach I am developing pages using HTML5, JQUERY and JSON. These pages will be included in android and iphone project and will be opened in webview control. Everything is working fine. Now I want to include payment gateway in my app. I read everywhere that iOS and Android will not allow to sale digital stuff using any payment gateway except in-app payment. I am looking this scenario because iOS and android charge 30% transaction fees while paypal will charge only 3%.

So please advise if I can use paypal for payment instead of in-app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834517/ios-paypal-simple-payment-with-multiple-objects/14834826#14834826

Comment: I have gone through above suggested link but it is still not clear if I can sale digital stuff like app content, functionality, services or subscription to my users. I just want to assure that once I implemented paypal gateway in my app and upload my app on app store then apple will not reject my app.

Comment: just implement and check then update me too....