# how to add the paypal sdk correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, paypal

iam developing one application.In that iam integrated paypal sdk.I added all frameworks whatever they mentioned.But i got the error like below

```
         Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
        "std::terminate()", referenced from:
  -[CardIOGPURenderer dealloc] in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
 "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOAnalytics.o)
  Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libPayPalMobile.a(CardIOGPURenderer.o)
```

How to solve this one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834517/ios-paypal-simple-payment-with-multiple-objects/14834826#14834826

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ganesh babu, did you follow this step from the [integration instructions](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/)?

> In your project’s Build Settings, add -lstdc++ -ObjC to Other Linker Flags.

Also, please make sure that you are using the [latest version of the sdk](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK).

Answer (score 0):

For integrating pay pal SDK Correctly

Have to do the following modifications

In C++ STandard Libray can use libstdC++ standard library

Enable all the modules

and finally other linker flags add it:  -lstdc++ -ObjC